# Cancelling tasks in the componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, gatsby

This is a common problem, yet I know why and can generally fix quickly.

However, on this occasion, I cannot seem to unmount the tasks in my ReactJS and GatsbyJS application.

The code below is listening to Firebase `auth` changes and the with `setState` is making the `auth` users details available within `state`

```
_initFirebase = false;

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    authUser: null
  };
}

firebaseInit = () => {
  const { firebase } = this.props;
  if (firebase && !this._initFirebase) {
    this._initFirebase = true;

    this.listener = firebase.onAuthUserListener(
      authUser => {
        localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser));
        this.setState({ authUser });
      },
      () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('authUser');
        this.setState({ authUser: null });
      }
    );
  }
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    authUser: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
  });

  this.firebaseInit();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.firebaseInit();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.listener && this.listener();
}
```

Causing an error in the console of

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 

This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in WithAuthentication (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Component (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by SigninPage)
    in SigninPage (created by HotExportedSigninPage)
    in AppContainer (created by HotExportedSigninPage)
    in HotExportedSigninPage (created by PageRenderer)
```

From my understanding, I have sufficiently `unmount` these `setState` tasks within `componentWillUnmount`.

Could you please explain what I may have missed?

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ firebase, is this `this.listener` actually an "unsubscriber"? Else i don't see why you'd call a "listener" in unmount hook

Comment: `this.listener` is called from a seperate file as `firebase.onAuthUserListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to setState after componentWillUnmount triggered...
you can not setState in componentWillUnmount.

The solution for your use case :

```
initFirebase = false;

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    authUser: null
  };
  // this prop to check component is live or not
  this.isAmAlive = false;

}



firebaseInit = () => {
  const { firebase } = this.props;
  if (firebase && !this._initFirebase) {
    this._initFirebase = true;

    this.listener = firebase.onAuthUserListener(
      authUser => {
        localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser));
          //check component is live or not if live update the component
          if(this.isAmAlive){
             this.setState({ authUser });
           }

      },
      () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('authUser');
         //check component is live or not if live update the component
         if(this.isAmAlive){
             this.setState({ authUser : null });
         }
      }
    );
  }
};

componentDidMount() {

  this.isAmAlive =true;

  this.setState({
    authUser: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
  });

  this.firebaseInit();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.firebaseInit();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.isAmAlive = false;
  this.listener && this.listener();
}
```